# Resized Image with Hover Animation does not fit into container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a put some images on the screen using that [Library](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid)

and it works fine for me!

Then I want to add a hover effect that I have found [here](http://callmenick.com/post/image-overlay-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions)

When I added the effect to the image down left in the left corner the layout was got some strange borders added.
Now it looks like that:

[image]

My HTML looks like that:

```
<div class="referencesPics"> 
            <div class="line1 ">
                <div class="leftPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                    <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="middlePic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                    <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="rightPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                    <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line2">
                <div class="leftPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="middlePic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                    <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>  
                <div class="rightPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                    <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="effect-2" class="line3 effects">
                <div class="leftPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid img">
                <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                <div class="overlay">
                    <a href="#" class="expand">+</a>
                    <!-- <a class="close-overlay hidden">x</a> -->
                </div>
                
                </div>
                  <div class="middlePic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                 <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div> 
                <div class="rightPic imgLiquidFill imgLiquid">
                <img alt="car" src="../img/media/referencesPic.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

The Script of Liquid Image resize library is copied exactly as in the sample code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid();
});
```

my CSS Code:

```
#section1.section .referencesPics {
    height:33.3333%;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line1 {
    height:100%;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line1 .leftPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line1 .middlePic {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line1 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#950049;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line2 {
    height:100%;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line2 .leftPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#950049;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line2 .middlePic {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line2 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 {
    height:100%;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 .leftPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 .middlePic {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:#F3A008;
    float: left;
}

#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#950049;
    float: left;
}
```

I have no idea what I should change to remove the white borders.
Has anyone a suggestion what I should change?

Thanks for help!

Comment: look at my answer bellow

Comment: @androitXperienceHunter Answer edited

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a conflict between you're two style from the plugging.

Maybe this can help you ?

```
#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#950049;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
```

You can try as well to move it to fit into you're container.

```
#section1.section .referencesPics .line3 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:#950049;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: that has either no effect on the layout

Comment: Is the border due to the hover effect ? What does your consol return you (if its returning you something) you can try to select the precise white border to see where it does comme from and what is here style

Comment: the border is visible from the loading moment on. But the hover effect does its work properly

Comment: What the heck... have you tried with negative value ? Just to see if the image move ??  If its not moving this is out of my competence sorry.